# How to sort lists of tuples from a query according to the lists value?

Tags: python, sql-server, list, sorting, tuples

I couldn't find a clear example  on how to sort tuples from a query. Here is my whole code:

```
import nltk //http://www.nltk.org/
import pypyodbc

text = raw_input()
token = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
print(token)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(token)
print(tagged)


class Database(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connected = False
        self.conn = None
        self.cur = None

    def connect(self):
        if not self.connected:
            self.conn = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=Dictionary')
            self.connected = True
            self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def search(self, lists):
        if not self.connected:
            self.connect()
        for word in lists:
            self.cur.execute('SELECT Ybanag FROM Words WHERE English IN (%s)' % (",".join('?'*len(lists))), lists)
            result = self.cur.fetchall()
            return result

get = Database()
this = get.search(token)
print(this)
```

and the output of this code is: (for example, I enter this sentence: `we all there`)(I've created database using SQL Server. Table name: `Words`, Columns: `English, Ybanag, POST`) and display their corresponding value in a column.)

```
['we', 'all', 'there'] //tokenize sentence
[('we', 'PRP'), ('all', 'DT'), ('there', 'RB')] //tokens and their POST(Part-Of-Speech Tag)
[('tore',), ('ngaming',), ('sittam',)] //their corresponding value in Ybanag from the dictionary
```

wherein `tore` is `there`, `ngaming` is `all` and `sittam` is `we`, as you can see, the 3rd line was not as `['we', 'all', 'there']` in sequence. What I mean is that from the query, how can I sort the output according to the sequence of the lists of the first line `['we', 'all', 'there']`? I want also to eliminate the symbols `[('',),]` in the last line of the ouput. This program tends to translate the input sentence into another language like `Ybanag`, a mother tongue language in Philippines.

Comment: I'm not sure where the second list comes from, can you elaborate?

Comment: Your code is not clear. Can you explain in more detail like 1) What you tried, 2) and what you expected.  If you modify your query a little bit, U may have the direct answer Eg : " SELECT ENGLISH,Ybanag FROM Words WHERE English IN (%s)" , Were u will get easy mapping for your English word and Ybanag. !!

Comment: Also, it looks like you're iterating over each word but then running the same sql each time. Oh, but you return within the for loop so the first iteration will be the only one. In this instance, the for loop is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to select the English word in the SQL as well, so that your 3rd line was a list of (english,ybanag) tuples. That way you could convert that to a dictionary and iterate over each word in the input list, retrieving the Ybanag equivalent in order:

```
self.cur.execute('SELECT English,Ybanag FROM Words WHERE English IN (%s)' % (",".join('?'*len(lists))), lists)
resultDict=dict(self.cur.fetchall())
outList=[]
for word in lists:
    outList.append(resultDict[word])
```

This doesn't solve the problem of words not found in the database, nor does it scale well if you are trying to convert a long sentence with many words.

Comment: OK, I understand what POST is now and it looks like you need to include POST in your search SQL. My comment above on your question about the for loop still applies. My answer is still what I think is the right approach for your problem, however, you will have to modify the dictionary key to include the original word AND the POST value.

Comment: My only other suggestion, if things get any more complicated with retrieving results from the database is to get each word individually as a separate query. Then you can iterate over the word list in order and structure your output as you go without having to look up results based on the input order.

Comment: the 3rd line sir in the output is not a tuples of English & Ybanag but just the Ybanag of the input sentence. I'm just new to python programming Sir. This is our thesis study. Since NLTK has these module (`tokenization,POST`) that runs in python, I thought that it would be easier for my team to work on the algorithm. Please help me sir specially in programming part then I'll credit you sir if our paper will be published. I need a python programmer/developer.

Comment: Also what I want or expected output is a plain text, no brackets,parenthesis,comma and single quotations, after sorting the lists, it will display this output: `sittam ngaming tore` :)